# What's the formal name for this Syntax?

Tags: list, scheme, lambda-calculus

Sometimes in Scheme, I have functions that take arguments like this

```
add 3 4
```

What do you call this kind of "list" where it's elements are like `a1 a2 a3` ? I don't think you can call it a list because lists are contained in parenthesis and elements are comma-seperated.

Comment: I thought proper scheme would be (add 3 4) and, well, it's a list, like it or not.  That's they way list look in Scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lisp uses [prefix or Polish notation syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_notation).

> Polish notation, also known as prefix
>   notation, is a form of notation for
>   logic, arithmetic, and algebra. Its
>   distinguishing feature is that it
>   places operators  to the left of their
>   operands. If the arity of the
>   operators is fixed, the result is a
>   syntax lacking parentheses or other
>   brackets, that can still be parsed
>   without ambiguity.

`add` is the operator and the right part are the operands.

The arity of the operators isn't fixed so Lisp uses parens in it's syntax to group the expressions.

Answer (score 4):

The (add 3 4) statement is  "function application" from the [lambda calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). The 3 4 from the expression are bindings for the parameters; alternatively, it is the parameter list for the function.

Comment: Yeah, but it's still a lit.  You can take a car of it.

Answer (score 4):

[s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression)?